# Why does an SQLite index not speed up my query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 2 tables:

**tblValidItems** - | - **tblItems**

```
validID        itemID
-------        ------
3              1
5              2
6              3
...            4
~ 8 K items    5
               ..... 
               ~ 20 K items
```

My query is to select certain things in `tblItems` that are also in `tblValidItems`:

```
SELECT tblItems.itemID FROM tblItems 
JOIN tblValidItems ON tblItems.itemID = tblValidItems.validID
```

I tried the query with and without an index on both tables, but the results varied vary little:

- With a indexes on both tables - 127ms
- With no index on either table - 132ms

This surprised me because I thought an index would dramatically effect the speed of this query.  Why dons't it?

Comment: are the ID columns primary keys?

Comment: Please post the schema.

Comment: the Engine encounters overhead if the IDs allow NULLS.  In addition if they are not of the same data type and the engine has to do an implicit conversion the index may not be used.  If statistics are off the indexes may not be used as well (say you created the index then  inserted the 8k valid items)  Lots of reasons why an optimizer may choose not to use the index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sqlite primary keys are indexed by default. You are joining on an indexed primary key anyway.

Whenever you have doubts on how sqlite will work with your query, use [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html)

Answer (score 5):

I am guessing that the query is dominated by the time to return the 8,000 values and not the time to find the rows.

Indexes are most useful when you are reducing the size of the data you are working with.  The reduction from 20k rows to 8k is not particularly signficant.